# Determining the order of polynomial regression

Tags: r, algorithm, regression, polynomials

Let assume that you have 
[image]

I am trying to write an algorithm to select a large M such that m < M. Then I would fit the model with m=M. Then if it happens that we reject the t test on the parameter Beta_{m}. Then, it stops and state that m is the degree; else, we set m=m-1 and continue until we stop.

```
set.seed(1234)
x <- rnorm(100,0,1)
y <- x + rnorm(100,x+0.5,0.5)
dat <- data.frame(cbind(x,y))

func <- function(dat,M) {
  dat <- as.matrix(dat)
  p_value <- list()
  if(length(dat[,1])>M){
    M=M-1
   break
  }
  for (i in 1:M) {
    model <- lm(dat[,1] ~ poly(dat[,-1],i,raw=TRUE))
    p_value[[i]] <- summary(model)$coefficients[i+1, 4]
    if (p_value[[i]]>0.05) {
      break
    } else {
      i=i+1
    }
    p_value1 = do.call(rbind, p_value)
  }
  return(c(p_value1,i-1))
}

func(dat,200)
# Error in func(dat, 200) : object 'p_value1' not found
```

However, with the code above I am not getting what I want with some errors. I was wondering if someone would help me out.

**Update**: when I run the code above I have gotten

```
> func(dat,200)
[1] 9.255452e-61 1.000000e+00
```

However, how to really account for "select a large M such that m < M" and how to show "m=m-1" every iteration. I meant how can I print out the coefficients each iteration and stop whenever the coefficient is not significant and show all the previous coefficient which are significant.

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: Error in func(dat, 200) : object 'p_value1' not found

Comment: The error is very important to help us. I edited your question to include it so that it will not be hidden in a comment (comments are easy to skip or miss when looking at question contents). I also edited to impost some indenting; this is more subjective, but it helps others see your functions and code in a well organized way. Third, you had a function call `y = x+norm(...)`, which I'm inferring should have been `y = x + rnorm(...)`; if I'm wrong, then correct me and then provide the package you are using to get that function (since `base::norm` is not useful there).

Comment: @r2evans well said! Thank you so much ! For my x and y, I was just generating data to illustrate my question.

Comment: Lastly, I loaded this function otherwise-unmodified and ran `func(dat,200)` and instead see `[1] 9.255452e-61 3.403253e-02 2.000000e+00`, which suggests this is not what you are doing to cause an error. There are some inefficiencies: `i=i+1` does nothing here, the value of `i` inside the loop is driven by `for`.